# Unable to choose a more specific candidate - Duplicate Resource

Tags: visual-studio, resources

I have a resource in my project called Lotto_0792, as you can see below, this resource is in my project once:

[image: Resources]

However, it shows up twice in intellisense:

[image: Intellisense]

And when I select either one, I get this error:

> Error 199 'Lotto_0792' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules
>   'MyProject.My.Resources.Resources' and
>   'MyProject.My.Resources.Resources'.

When I mouse-over, I get the following screen-tip:

[image: Screentip]

I have checked the Resources.resx file, each resource appears only once.

This is preventing my solution from building. What could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same error. Please check if the resource file Lotto_0792 created a second designer file.

For example:

```
Lotto_0792.designer.vb
```

and

```
Lotto_07921.designer.vb
```

Comment: This is exactly what had happened, had already figured it out but marking it as the answer as it is indeed correct, cheers :)